# Preferred Unit Test for REDHAWK SDR Component

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm looking for an example of a unit test for a REDHAWK component. In particular, I'd like a test where I can provide packet(s) to an input port and verify the correct packet(s) are pushed from an output port. Is there a preferred way to do this with REDHAWK? I'm struggling to find documentation or examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example used by the HardLimit Component:

https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/HardLimit/blob/develop-1.0/tests/test_HardLimit.py

Basically, in the setUp method, a DataSource and DataSink from the REDHAWK Sandbox (sb) module are created, are started along with the Component, and then connected in the appropriate order.

Next, any method that starts with 'test' is run by the unit testing suite. Generally these methods will provide an array of data to the DataSource, which will format the data into BULKIO format and push to your Component. Assuming the Component is working correctly, it will push data to the DataSink, which can be checked periodically for new data. Once the data has been received, it can be validated as appropriate before the tearDown method is called.

Finally, the tearDown method stops and releases the Component and cleans up the source and sink.

This is the basic approach for testing a Component. There are more options available for sourcing and sinking data, which can be found by running the following in a python interpreter:

```
from ossie.utils import sb
help(sb)
```

This will also provide methods for plotting data and audio playback, among other miscellaneous utilities.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score -1):

It is fairly easy with RedHawk to add a couple of new components: one to send packets to the component being tested and one to receive output packets.  I make a sender or source packet using the serviceFunction() in sender.cpp which is called periodically if each call returns NORMAL, adding a usleep() if you want to control the rate.  It should send a valid packet to its this->PortName->MethodName().  It can also randomly send bad packets too if you want to test how the component under test handles them.  You can even add a component property to set the rate (using the value in the usleep).

The receiver or sink component can receive the packets in port_impl.cpp  in MethodName() and do whatever test you want to test validity and either log the result of the test or use cout<